# @can directive issue - laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, authorization

jobs.edit.blade.php can be accessed by registered users

out of them the accountant can access some checkboxes(only visible to him)

The database values are changed(Boolean) according to checkboxes submitted by the accountant.

```
@can ('isAccountant')
//some code with checkboxes
@endcan
```

The problem is, when a registered user access jobs.edit.blade.php
and submits(Checkboxes are not visible), all the Boolean values in the database becomes Zero

How can i avoid this situation

jobs.edit.blade.php

```
@can ('isAccountant')
<div class="row">
  <div id="status">
     @if ($job->entered_status == '0')
      <input type="checkbox" name="entered_status" @if($job->entered_status) checked @endif> Entered <br><br>
     @elseif ($job->entered_status == '1')
      <input type="checkbox" name="entered_status" checked value="1" disabled> Entered <br><br>
      <input type='hidden' name='entered_status' value="1">
     @endif

    @if ($job->sales_status == '1')
      <input type="checkbox" name="despatch_status" checked value="1" disabled> All Despatches Completed <br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_status" checked value="1" disabled> All Invoices Completed
      <input type='hidden' name='despatch_status' value="1">
      <input type='hidden' name='invoice_status' value="1">
    @endif

    @if ($job->sales_status == '0' && $job->job_status == 'Completed' && $job->despatch_status == '0')
      <input type="checkbox" name="despatch_status" @if($job->despatch_status) checked @endif value="1"> All Despatches Completed <br><br>
    @endif

    @if ($job->sales_status == '0' && $job->job_status == 'Completed' && $job->despatch_status == '1')
      <input type="checkbox" name="despatch_status" checked value="1"> All Despatches Completed <br><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="invoice_status" @if($job->invoice_status) checked @endif value="1"> All Invoices Completed <br><br>
    @endif
  </div>
</div>

@endcan
```

JobController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {


      $job = Job::find($id);
      $job->customer_name = $request->customer_name;
      $job->company_name = $request->company_name;
      $job->job_type = $request->job_type;
      $job->job_owner = $request->job_owner;
      $job->job_status = $request->job_status;
      $job->despatch_status = $request->has('despatch_status');
      $job->invoice_status = $request->has('invoice_status');
      if ($job->despatch_status == 1 && $job->invoice_status == 1) {
        $job->sales_status = 1;
      }
      $job->entered_status = $request->has('entered_status');
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('isAdmin', function ($user) {
          return $user->user_type == 'Admin';
        });

        Gate::define('isDirector', function ($user) {
          return $user->user_type == 'Director';
        });

        Gate::define('isProduction', function ($user) {
          return $user->user_type == 'Production';
        });

        Gate::define('isAccountant', function ($user) {
          return $user->user_type == 'Accountant';
        });


    }
```

Extended Error

```
_token  
"nzY5y8EW5yupkL3d6aL9bcpZRYmlc5YTN94ee1uI"
_method 
"PATCH"
id  
"10725"
customer_name   
""
company_name    
""
job_type    
"""
Item:\r\n
Qty:\r\n
Size:\r\n
Paper:\r\n
Print:\r\n
Each:\r\n
Total:
"""
job_owner   
"Sam"
job_status  
"Pending"
job_delivery_date   
""
job_delivery_time   
""
pk_pkl  
"PKL"
entered_status  
"on"
```

Comment: 1) could you add the entire blade file which the can resides in? 2) could you add the controller code that handles the request? 3) could you share your policy/gate ?

Comment: @Quezler Code Entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that you are using:

`$job->despatch_status = $request->has('despatch_status')`

`$request->has('despatch_status')` is true if the request **has** the field, and false if the request does **not** have the field.

The code i can recommend:

This will get the `despatch_status` from the request, if its `true` or `false` (or `1`/`0`) it will get passed to `$job->despatch_status`.

But if `despatch_status` is **not** present in the request, the `->get()` will return `null`, so the `??` operator will then read the value already in the database, so then it wont change.

```
$job->despatch_status = $request->get('despatch_status') ?? $job->despatch_status;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank you for the explanation. This sorted the issue. :).

Comment: a very unusual error, trying to figure out but couldn't
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column 'entered_status' at row 1 (SQL: update `jobs` set `entered_status` = on, `updated_at` = 2018-05-23 16:24:27 where `id` = 10714)

Comment: mentioned a dd($request->all()
 "entered_status" => "on" , that's the issue can't figure out from where "on" is assigned "entered_status" => "on" only when the checkbox is selected. When the checkbox is blank "entered_status" is not passed –

Comment: what browser are you using @zaster?

Comment: i am using Chrome

Comment: checked with Firefox also. Same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments of the other answer, add this to your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    //

    parent::boot();

    if (!$this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        foreach (request()->all() as $key => $value) {
            if (is_string($value) && $value === 'on') {
                request()->offsetSet($key, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this will do is scan all incoming fields, and if they are `'on'` they get cast to `true`.

(the reason we add this to a service provider and not middleware is based on order of execution)

Comment: @Qyezler Thank you very much. Your code worked nicely. But how on earth is it possible a value like "on" is assigned in the first place

Comment: @zaster i wish i knew :(

Comment: check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox
"If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on" problem solved in the proper way. Thank you very much for guiding throughout this whole issue :)